# Extend server code so server is able to interact wit clients using multithreading.So the no of clients sim connected the same server

Tags: java, multithreading

*Cant figure out the question above. have tried oracle tutorials and note however I am still unable to do it. any help would be greatly appreciated.

The weight conversion server given on Blackboard (ConversionServerNoConcurrency.java) can interact with multiple
clients, but only in a sequential manner (that is, a new client instance can connect to the server only after the server has
finished dealing with the previous client).
Extend/modify the given server code so that the server is able to interact with multiple clients in parallel (concurrently),
using multithreading. The number of clients simultaneously connected to the same server should not be restricted.

really need some help with the code as other wise I wont be able to implicate it when doing my assignment

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ConversionServerNoConcurrency {
private Socket s;
private Scanner in;
private PrintWriter out;
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(8888);

    ConversionServerNoConcurrency serverInstance = new         ConversionServerNoConcurrency();

    System.out.println("Server running. Waiting for a client to connect...");

    while (true) {

        serverInstance.s = server.accept();

        System.out.println("Client connected");

        serverInstance.run();

        System.out.println("Client disconnected. Waiting for a new client to connect...");
    }
}
public void run() {
    try {
        try {

            in = new Scanner(s.getInputStream());

            out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());

            doService(); 

        } finally {
            s.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
}
public void doService() throws IOException {

    while (true) {

        if (!in.hasNext())
            return;

        String request = in.next();

        System.out.println("Request received from client: \'" + request + "\'");

        if (!request.equals("QUIT")) // end connection with this client 
            handleConversionRequest(request);

    }
}
public void handleConversionRequest(String request) {

    String amountStr = in.next();

    double amount = Double.valueOf(amountStr);

    System.out.println("Amount received from client: " + amount);

    if (request.equals("CONVERT_TO_POUNDS")) {
        out.println(amount * 2.2d); // send conversion result to client
        System.out.println("Sent conversion result to client");
    } else if (request.equals("CONVERT_TO_KGS")) {
        out.println(amount / 2.2d); 
        System.out.println("Sent conversion result to client");
    } else
        System.err.println("Unknown request!");

       out.flush();
     }
}
```

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class ConversionClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
        Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 8888);
        InputStream instream= s.getInputStream();
        OutputStream outstream= s.getOutputStream();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(instream);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outstream);
        out.print("CONVERT_TO_KGS 123.45\n");  // we send the 1st request to the server
        out.flush();
        String response = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Received from server: " + response);
        Thread.sleep(2000); // delay the next request a bit
        out.print("CONVERT_TO_POUNDS 56\n");  // 2nd request
        out.flush();
        response = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Received from server: " + response);
        Thread.sleep(2000); // delay the next request a bit
        out.print("CONVERT_TO_POUNDS 836.98\n");  // 3rd request
        out.flush();
        response = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Received from server: " + response);
        out.print("QUIT\n");  
        out.flush();
        s.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: There are thousands of examples of multithreaded servers even on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Writing Concurrent Connection Oriented Servers is an important Subject in Computer Science/Software Engineering. So even if you don't know how to code you have to understand the following.

1. In a Iterative Connection Oriented Server just like `ConversionServerNoConcurrency` you have, It will have only one Thread (Main Thread) receive connections and service connections.
2. You need to separate Receiving Connection and Servicing Connections into two different Threads if you want to develop Concurrent Connection Oriented Servers.
3. If you see `ConversionServerConcurrency` below, the Connection Receiving is done by Main Thread and It Delegates the Connection Servicing to threads in the `execService` pool. It is important to use a Thread Pool to avoid DDoS attacks. Because with a Thread Pool there is a Maximum limit on how many Threads can be spawned.
4. Have a look at `ConversionServerTask` which now has all the logic to Service connections.

   ```
   import java.io.*;
   import java.net.*;
   import java.util.Scanner;
   import java.util.concurrent.*;
   public class ConversionServerConcurrency {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

       ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(8888);

       System.out.println("Server running. Waiting for a client to connect...");

       ExecutorService execService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

       while (true) {

           Socket clientSocket = server.accept();

           execService.submit(new ConversionServerTask(clientSocket));

           System.out.println("Waiting for a new client to connect...");
       }
   }

   public static class ConversionServerTask implements Runnable {
       private Socket s;
       private Scanner in;
       private PrintWriter out;

       public ConversionServerTask(Socket clientSocket) {
           this.s = clientSocket;
       }


       public void run() {
           System.out.println("Client connected");
           try {
               try {

                   in = new Scanner(s.getInputStream());

                   out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());

                   doService();

               } finally {
                   s.close();
               }
           } catch (IOException e) {
               System.err.println(e);
           } finally {
               System.out.println("Client disconnected");
           }
       }
       public void doService() throws IOException {

           while (true) {

               if (!in.hasNext())
                   return;

               String request = in.next();

               System.out.println("Request received from client: \'" + request + "\'");

               if (request.equals("QUIT")) {// end connection with this client 
                   break;
               } else {
                   handleConversionRequest(request);
               }

           }
       }
       public void handleConversionRequest(String request) {

           String amountStr = in.next();

           double amount = Double.valueOf(amountStr);

           System.out.println("Amount received from client: " + amount);

           if (request.equals("CONVERT_TO_POUNDS")) {
               out.println(amount * 2.2d); // send conversion result to client
               System.out.println("Sent conversion result to client");
           } else if (request.equals("CONVERT_TO_KGS")) {
               out.println(amount / 2.2d);
               System.out.println("Sent conversion result to client");
           } else
               System.err.println("Unknown request!");

           out.flush();
       }
   }


   }
   ```

Comment: You must have Java Version 1.7+